# Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count gives overflow error when single row result from filter

Tags: excel, vba, selection

When using `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count` to count a single column of filtered data, it works great for multiple row results. But when ever there is only 1 row displayed, it gives me an overflow error or I get count = 107564 (I forget the actual number).

Comment: Can you share more of the code. Just re-run the macro to get the exact error message - what is the error message? Also, are you sure any visible cells are selected?

Answer (score 2):

`.Count` is of type `Long` but newer Excel versions have more cells per worksheet (`17,179,869,184` Cells) than `Long` can handle (maximum `2,147,483,647`). So if you select a huge amount ouf cells they exceed `Long` and therefore you get an overflow error.

To solve this you need to use the [Range.CountLarge property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.countlarge) instead of the [Range.Count property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.count) which is of type `LongLong` and can handle this amount of cells.

| Data type | Storage size | Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Long (Long integer) | 4 bytes | -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 |
| LongLong (LongLong integer) | 8 bytes | -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (Valid on 64-bit platforms only.) |

*<sup>Table source: [Office VBA Reference - Data type summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary).</sup>*

This should not throw an overflow error:

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).CountLarge
```

There is a simple rule: When it comes to counting rows or columns `.Count` is fine but everytime you are counting cells (in multiple rows or columns) you need to ensure to use `.CountLarge` to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that if you select only 1 cell then excel works out all visible cells in the sheet. Selecting one cell and running this line:

```
Debug.Print Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
```

gave me `$1:$13,$15:$17,$19:$19,$28:$37,$39:$39,$41:$52,$54:$81,$83:$1048576`. Counting the number of cells in this range using `.Count` results in an overflow error

This is obviously not the behaviour you want. As a workaround try something like this:

```
Function CountVisibleCells() As Long
    Dim rngSelection As Range
    Set rngSelection = Selection
    CountVisibleCells = 0
    If rngSelection.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
        CountVisibleCells = rngSelection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.CountLarge
    ElseIf Not rngSelection.EntireRow.Hidden And _
           Not rngSelection.EntireColumn.Hidden Then
        CountVisibleCells = 1
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Actually this won't solve the issue. If the number of selected cells is above `2,147,483,647` this will still overflow! That is still possible in your code because Excel has `17,179,869,184` cells per worksheet. See my answer for explanation.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I was just typing that :D. the line `If rngSelection.Cells.Count > 1 Then` will fail if the rngSelection has more cells than what count can handle

Comment: @Pᴇʜ @SiddharthRout Hey guys. Please read the OP's question again and tell me if I am missing something. OP is getting this error when selecting ONE cell in a column. However, even if OP selects an entire column `.Count` should work. If OP has only one cell visible then the expected number is 1 (not the result returned by `.CountLarge`. I am open to further comments :)

Comment: The issue is that the code is not safe. I didn't say it *will fail* but it easily *can*. It is good practice to write code that can not end up in an unhandled exception. This can easily be achieved with using `.CountLarge` and there is no advatage of not doing it. • Since you don't know how many cells of results the OP has and if the filter returns a lot of visible cells it can exceed `Long`. You can argument that most people don't have that much data, but I had several times. And there is no reason to write vulnerable or bad code.

Comment: Your code is working around the actual issue instead of fixing the issue itself.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The OP said "to count a single column". The maximum number of cells in a column is 1,048,576 which is handled OK by `Long`. The real issue here - as I understand it - is that the OP is getting a large number that overflows when the expected number is `1`. I am therefore, trying to work out the expected "correct" number. On the other hand, what you're doing is saying to the OP, here is a container that will handle that super large number to prevent overflowing and ignoring the fact that number itself is incorrect.

Comment: The fact that the OP got an overflow on `.Count` means that `Selection` contains more cells than `Long` can handle (otherwise the error would not have been there). Now you do `If rngSelection.Cells.Count > 1 Then` on the same selection. Guess which error that will produce. That is why you need `.CountLarge` here. If `Selection` would have been *"a single column"* as you state there would not have been the error in the first place. You see what I mean?

Comment: The thing is that the visible cells `rngSelection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count` of a range `rngSelection` can obviously only be less cells than `rngSelection.Cells.Count` because the visible cells of that range can only be a subset of the range itself. So if `rngSelection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count` causes an overflow then `rngSelection.Cells.Count` definitly must cause an overflow too. • And if `rngSelection` does only contain hidden cells you get a *"no cells found"* error not an overflow.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ You said *"the visible cells of that range can only be a subset of the range itself"*. This is exactly what I thought, and this is why I found this question interesting. If `rngSelected` is more than one cell then your statement is correct. However, when `rngSelected` is **only one** cell and there are hidden rows/columns then `rngSelection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` returns a range of **all** visible cells in the **entire** sheet. Of course when you count **all** visible cells in a sheet in a `Long` you get an overflow.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ By the way I find this counter-intuitive and I don't know why it works this way. They must have a good reason (or it could even be a bug). Please try it: Hide at least one row, select **only one** cell and run the code `Debug.Print Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address`

Comment: @SuperSymmetry Huh yes, that is indeed a strange behaviour. If `Selection` is A1 then `Selection.Cells.CountLarge` is `1` but `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` refers to all visible cells of the entire sheet. That means `Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` does something entirely different if `Rng` is a single cell versus `Rng` beeing a range of multiple cells. And no word about that in the documentation. Thanks Microsoft! • Looks like they tried do be smart and made it worse. Now I see what you tried to work around with your code. Anyway I would use `CountLarge` to be safe.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ changed it to `CountLarge`. As you said there's no harm using it. What is even more peculiar is that if there's no hidden rows/columns in the sheet and you select only one cell then `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` results in the expected one cell: Very strange :) Anyway, I am glad you got my point.

Comment: That is even more weird. I cannot explain that behavior and to me it looks neiter useful nor following any logic. But I can confirm it and it looks like a bug to me. But well not the first one, just another one in the long list of *"strange behavoirs of VBA"* ;)

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I'll give this a go and see if it works.